# Can't change textbox text

Tags: c#

This works well:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
         textBox1.Text = "dsfsdfsd";
    }
```

but when i use it like this it never works the textbox1.text successfully Chang in the compiler but the text doesn't show anything

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.click();
    }

public  void click()
    {
        textBox1.Text= "asdasdas";
    }
```

please advise why I can't change the text box text from any methods except the method that deals directly with the user (buttons) even if I put a bridge method between the (button) method and `textbox1.text=("asdasdas");` method, it never works. please advise.

Comment: Can it be that you call click on a new created From which is not shown?

Comment: I recommend reading some good book on OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're `new`ing a new `Form1` instance. The `button1_Click` is a member of `Form1`, so you already have a `Form1` instance that you need to be operating on.

i.e.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.click(); // or just `click();`
}

public  void click()
{
    textBox1.Text= "asdasdas";
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: thank you so much i understande the concept now but what if i wanna call the click method from program.cs.i used this code

form1.cs
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.bridge();        
        }


program.cs 

    public static void bridge()     
        {

            Form1 there  = new Form1();
            there.click();
         
        }

form1.cs

      public  void click()
        {
            textBox1.Text= "asdasdas";
     textBox1.TextChanged += newEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);

         }

Comment: user2523189, I think you need to learn the basics of object orientated programming to further your knowledge in this area.  Your program starts with a Main() method which is a static method.  From here, you can run a sequence of commands (method calls) or more likely, create an instance of a class (such as a form) and call a single method on it.  In this example, you have your Form1 doing that - you don't need to look at program.cs again.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    click();
}
```

You don't need to create a new instance of the form to call one of its methods.

Comment: @user2523189 Your click method cannot be static as it references instance fields.

Answer (score 2):

You should subscribe to the `TextChanged` event **BEFORE** actually changing the text, otherwise the event handler is not yet attached:

```
public void click()
{
    textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    textBox1.Text = "asdasdas";
}
```

Also you shouldn't be subscribing multiple times to the same event when the click method is called. It would be better to perform this subscription only once, for example in the constructor:

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    public void click()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "asdasdas";
    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }    
}
```

Comment: Does that really matter (given that the eventhandler does nothing)? He should show the form instead.

Comment: Of course that it matters. He subscribes to the TextChanged event after he has changed the text and expects the event to be triggered. In his example the event is empty but I guess he expects it to be triggered.

Comment: Ok, you might be right. I think he instantiates another `Form1` which he fails to show, and calls click on that instance, thus wondering why the text is not updated in the instance of `Form1` that is instantiated in the `Main` method. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: i think this is true klaus but what i should do to callt he form1 which im showing

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling `click()` method on new `Form` instance, change your code to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    click();
}

public  void click()
{
    textBox1.Text= "asdasdas";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new instance of the form and clicking on that, which isn't the form you're looking at so you won't see the change.

Instead just call the `Click()` method of this form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete guide how to make a Windows form app. You have to start learning from the basics.
[Your First C# Windows Form](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s1p5.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Program.bridge` call is causing confusions.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.bridge();        
}
```

In that method you are instantiating a new `Form1`. This will have no effect on the form that is already displaying. Try to alter your `button1_click` function in the following way and see if it helps:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.click();        
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you ***must*** use the `bridge` approach, you can do it like this in your `Program.cs`:

```
public static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        TheForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(TheForm);
    }

    private static Form1 TheForm { get; set; }

    public static void bridge()
    {
        TheForm.Click();
    }
}
```

I do not recommend this approach, but if you must...

Comment: like this it works ,but i want to change the text from program.cs becouse i need this feature in my code :)

Comment: @user2523189 then you must restructure your code. In program.cs you must the save a reference to the form so that you can manipulate it later.

Comment: thank you so much ur solution worked and now i understande the concept .but why don't you recommend this solution .what if my code should change somthing in the user interface ,is there another solution if my code should change somthing in the user interface ?..thank you for your time